# How to reload Iframe content at a time interval so that it does not flicker

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iframe, flicker

I have kept Iframe inside update panel but then also it flickers every time it reload. I think I can use javascript to load my content of Iframe in order to make it flicker free.Is this way correct? If yes, then How can I do it? And if not, then What should I do?

This is the code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="width:100%; height: 195px; margin-left: -7px;">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderChatRequest" runat="server">
                <iframe id="iframe1" frameborder="0" style=" width: 379px;
                        height:110%;" src="frmChatRequest.aspx"
                        scrolling="no" runat="server">
                </iframe>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: How about using JavaScript's `setInterval()` function to make an AJAX request to the server (HTTP Handler) that returns the HTML you want to  reload? This serves two benefits, it gets rid of the `iframe` and the partial post back of the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: How can I do it.Please give me the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this, use `setInterval()` with `load()`

```
      $(function(){    
        setInterval(function(){
          $( "#result" ).load( "frmChatRequest.aspx", function() {
            alert( "Load was performed." );
           });
        }, 10000);         
    });
```

HTML: Remove `iframe` and add below `div` there

```
     <div id="result" ></div>
```

Comment: +1 Good call on the jQuery `.load()` function with `setInterval()` function.

Comment: Do I need Any plugIn or what?

Comment: You need to include jquery latest version file

Comment: Ok But I have some controls in frmChatRequest.aspx page and their event is not firing, it is giving some error